# How can we create a super or sub-script text in flutter like we used to create in android using Spannable String class?

Tags: android, dart, flutter, hybrid-mobile-app

I want to create a superscript text like 2^4 then how can I do this in the flutter. If someone knows please let me know.

Comment: That's currently not directly supported by Flutter. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/224, https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12675. You would need to position text spans yourself

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question in one liner

```
final String twoRaisedToFour = '2\u2074';
```

To know more about such unicodes refer to following answer
[unicode list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54255383/1441732)

If this helps do accept the answer. Thank you :)

Comment: This is in fact the official Flutter answer to this question: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10906#issuecomment-385723664
(There's also https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/224 where doing superscript/subscript in general is one of a long list of features they might add someday, but Unicode is the official answer until then.)

Comment: @GregPrice I am also waiting for this feature till then, EasyRichText library is the option though it is bit different than RichText as you cannot use it directly as a String which I reckon is a deal breaker.

Answer (score 0):

RichText class might help you - https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html It is very similar to Spannable string in Android

Comment: That is a lot like SpannableString in Android, but it doesn't have this feature. (Because Flutter currently doesn't have this feature at all; see issue linked in a comment on the question.)

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice. There is a library that could help you to achieve desired effect: https://pub.dev/packages/easy_rich_text

Answer (score 0):

If you need a widget then you can go with `Text.rich` widget or if you need a text alone then you can create `List<TextSpan>` with the text you have and make into a single text