# SuperScript and SubScript in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, superscript

I use the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54254516/how-can-we-use-superscript-and-subscript-text-in-flutter-text-or-richtext) and insert a superscript, it works fine just like this[image]

Now ,is it possible to edit the superscript fontFamily? I tried this and it dosen't work.the only thing that I can edit is the color.

```
Text("2500"+"TND", style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Avenir',color: Colors.blue)),
```

This code will return this result :[image]

Comment: did you add font family to your pubspec.yaml ?

Comment: Yes, I am already using it in the whole app and It works fine.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, subscript and superscript are [not yet supported by Flutter](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10906#issuecomment-385723664), and they are still working in progress as mentioned in [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10906#issuecomment-385723664):

> For those specific examples you can use the relevant Unicode
> characters. For a generic solution, we don't currently have a way to
> control the vertical alignment of text spans; that's one of the bullet
> points in [#224](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/224).

As a workaround, you can try the sample in [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10906#issuecomment-588294533) using [RichText](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html) and [Transform.translate](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Transform/Transform.translate.html);

> You can try with RichText widget and Transform.transalte widget:
>
> ```
> RichText(
>   text: TextSpan(
>     style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 16),
>     children: [
>       TextSpan(
>         text: 'Some text ',
>       ),
>       WidgetSpan(
>         child: Transform.translate(
>           offset: const Offset(0.0, 4.0),
>           child: Text(
>             'subscripts',
>             style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11),
>           ),
>         ),
>       ),
>       WidgetSpan(
>         child: Transform.translate(
>           offset: const Offset(0.0, -7.0),
>           child: Text(
>             'supscripts',
>             style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11),
>           ),
>         ),
>       ),
>       TextSpan(
>         text: 'Some text ',
>       ),
>     ],
>   ),
> );
> ```

The same workaround was also used in [one of the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61748312) in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54254516/how-can-we-use-superscript-and-subscript-text-in-flutter-text-or-richtext);

Testing the workaround, you can now change the font family of the superscript/subscript:

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        fontFamily: 'RobotoMono',
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Column(
              children: [
                RichText(
                  text: TextSpan(
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      fontSize: 16,
                      fontFamily: 'Shizuru',
                    ),
                    children: [
                      TextSpan(
                        text: '-2,500',
                      ),
                      WidgetSpan(
                        child: Transform.translate(
                          offset: const Offset(0.0, -7.0),
                          child: Text(
                            'TND',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 11,
                              fontFamily: 'RobotoMono',
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Note: I've used the [`Shizuru`](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Shizuru?query=shizu) and [`Roboto Mono`](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto+Mono?query=roboto) font family to visually compare the difference.

Answer (score 1):

#### This is a simple and straightforward way of achieving Subscript and SuperScript in flutter.

1. Use a `Row` widget
2. Add your first `Text` widget. The base text
3. Use `Transform` widget with `translate` factory constructor to `Elevate` or `Bring down` your text

#### Here is a simple example

```
Row(
              children: [
                Text(
                  '24',
                  style: context.textTheme.bodyLarge!.copyWith(
                    fontSize: 24,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
                Transform.translate(
                  offset: const Offset(0, -7.5),
                  child: Text(
                    '°C',
                    style: context.textTheme.bodyLarge!.copyWith(
                      fontSize: 14,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```