# Flutter - how to place the text to the right above the text?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I need to implement this in my application:

[image]

I need to place the text on the top right above the main texts. how is it easier to do it?
I can use this plugin - [align_positioned](https://pub.dev/packages/align_positioned).

But I'm wondering how to implement this using standard methods.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54254516/how-can-we-use-superscript-and-subscript-text-in-flutter-text-or-richtext

Answer (score 1):

You can use this package https://pub.dev/packages/rich_editor.

In pub.dev you can see example with *superscript*