# Flutter: How to make upper/bottom index to Text()

Tags: flutter, text

Does anybody knows how to make (in a easy way) upper index in text field?

My code:

```
Row(
   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
   crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline,
   textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
       children: [
          Text(
             widget.weather.temp.round().toString(),
             style: TextStyle(
                 color: Colors.white,
                 fontSize: 150,
               ),
          Text(
             '°C',
             style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 50.0,
             ),
          )
       ],
),
```

This code gives me bottom aligmnet (index)

[image: Bottom index example]

and how to make upper index like this:

[image: Upper index example]

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54254516/how-can-we-use-superscript-and-subscript-text-in-flutter-text-or-richtext

Answer (score 2):

Try this text

```dart
Text("${widget.weather.temp.round().toString()}\u00b0\u1d9c")
```

Comment: It works, but is there a better way to top align of text? Using baseline widget?